# How can I make form values appear as URL segments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a store site that uses MVC 4. I'm having trouble getting the route right. Currently it just posts the search string. I want it to display the search string every time. In the site layout I have a search box that uses this code:

_SiteLayout.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Catalog"))
{
     <div class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("searchString", "", new Dictionary<string, object> {{"placeholder", "Enter something to search"}, {"class", "form-control input-search"}})
          <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-default no-border-left" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </span>
      </div>
}
```

My routeconfig uses this:

RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Search",
        "Catalog/Search/{searchString}",
        new {controller = "Catalog", action = "Search", searchString = string.Empty});
```

When someone enters something into the search box on the page, it redirects them to /Catalog/Search. The search functionality works great, but I want it to show this url:
 /Catalog/Search/i+searched+for+something

Any assistance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is beyond the control of MVC. If you submit a form via POST, the form values will be submitted in the request body. If you submit via GET, the values will be created on the query string. This is controlled by the browser.

Immediately, I can see one possible solution, which is to accept the values on the query string and redirect to the same action using the query value as a route parameter instead (edit: thinking about it, this should still work if the original request is a POST):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Catalog", FormMethod.GET))
```

And then in your action:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["searchString"]))
    { 
        return RedirectToAction("Search", new { searchString });
    }

    /* Do the rest of your processing here */
}
```

This should check if the value was in the query string and, if it was, regenerate the GET request to the same action. Because MVC is now in control, it should take your route into account and put the parameter in the path instead of the query string.

This is, of course, an extra HTTP request for every search but that should be fairly trivial.

Alternatively, you could use jQuery to read the form value, construct the URL and perform the redirect.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I needed. I also had to change the searchString in the route config to UrlParameter.Optional instead of defaulting to string.Empty. It was just setting it to empty every time. At this point the url looks like "/Catalog/Search/i searched for something", but I can figure out how to change the spaces to a +. EDIT: And yes, it does still work if it's a post instead of a get.